# Modifying intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml causes app not to install using adb

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to launch my app from a url.  After I add the following code to my AndroidManifest.xml, I'm unable to install my app using adb.

```
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="xyz.myurl.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/social/print/v2/"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
```

I'm not seeing any error.  If I delete the above code, I'm able to install my app on my device using adb.  I'm unable to understand why this is happening.  Can someone point me to the right direction?

thanks.

Comment: An install failure will typical generate messages in logcat

Comment: Thanks Chris.  But there was no install failure.  in the terminal it showed success when I ran the adb -d install -r <apk_file> command

Comment: Perhaps you misreported the issue then - installed, but unable to launch, is not the same as not installed.

Comment: Yes, I was confused because I never saw any icon for the app in my phone.  So I thought app did not get installed.  Sorry for my confusion.  I wrote an answer below why this error was occurring.

Answer (score 1):

modify it like this

```
<data
                android:host="xyz.myurl.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/social/print/v2/"
                android:scheme="http" />
            </data>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured what the issue was.  intent-filter tag needs to be split up. one for main and launcher, and the other for launch from url specific filter